# How to populate a postgresql database by data retrieved from APIs by using loop insert or by Bulk Insert through a txt or csv file?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, bulkinsert, psycopg2

The code shown below connects to two separate URLs and print the data retrieved from them. `Item` and `Item2` are the selected dictionaries i need to deal with.

```js
import urllib2
import json

#assign the url
url="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/swd_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22operacja%22:%22stacje%22}"
# open the url 
json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(str(url))
output= json.load(json_obj)
station_res= output ['data'] ['features']
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as f:
 for item in station_res:

  station= item['id']
  
#for station in station_res:
  url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:" +str(station)+ "}"  
  json_obj2= urllib2.urlopen(str(url1))
  output2= json.load(json_obj2)
  try:
   for item2 in output2 ['data']:
    print item['id'], item2['rok'], item2['miesiac'], item2['dzien'], item2['godzina'], item2['minuta'], item2['temperatura'], item2['wilgotnosc'], item2['opad'], item2['kierunek_wiatru'], item2['predkosc_wiatru'], item2['dewpoint'], item2['cisnienie']
    json.dump ((item['id'], item2['rok'], item2['miesiac'], item2['dzien'], item2['godzina'], item2['minuta'], item2['temperatura'], item2['wilgotnosc'], item2['opad'], item2['kierunek_wiatru'], item2['predkosc_wiatru'], item2['dewpoint'], item2['cisnienie']),f)
  except KeyError:
   pass
```

Now i have a postgresql database where in one of the schemas present there, i have a specific table whose column structure is exactly the same as i printed out in the last of the above code and the goal is to insert these data retrieved from the APIs. 
Also the catch is , for each value of `item['id']` i need to call my `url1` and the whole data from `url1` sorted by only item2 along with its identifiers (e.g `item2['rok'], item2['mesiac']...`) need to be in the specific table in the database plus also the respective value of `item['id']` (from `url`) every time.

On second thought, i just want to know if this whole thing can be done more easily by retrieving the whole data in the required format (as the code prints) in a `txt` file or `csv` file and then do a bulk insert in the database? I think this might make the task easier rather than looping an insert every time.

The code above also makes a txt file which contains the required data to be inserted in the table which is present in a schema inside the database. Using `psycopg2` on `python 2.7` please suggest me the code for the best approach, which i think is the bulk insert with `txt` file. Thanks.

Comment: I would write out to a file and then insert that into the database. I think it'll be faster. If you do it with a loop, don't open and close the connection on every iteration. That'll take forever.

Comment: I agree with @holyland, the simplest approach is to output a CSV file that can be imported, or an SQL file that can be run

Comment: Thanks but can anyone help me with the insertion, as in the above script i already made the txt file (i guess txt file or csv file makes no difference). Now i need to extend the python script to do populate the data in the table.